# Eigenstates with specific eigenvalue in python

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I have a very large matrix, but I only want to find the eigenvectors (more than 1) with one specific eigenvalue. How can I get this without solving the whole eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix in python?

Comment: I don't know how to convert my np.mat(A) matrix to sparse matrix...

Comment: it's not necessary to use a sparse matrix, I have posted an example...

Answer (score 0):

One option could be perhaps to use shift-invert method. The method `eigs` in scipy has an optional parameter `sigma` using which it is possible to specify the value close to which it should search for eigenvalues:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs

np.random.seed(42)

N = 10
A = np.random.random_sample((N, N))
A += A.T
A += N*np.identity(N)

#get N//2 largest eigenvalues
l,_ = eigs(A, N//2)
print(l)

#get 2 eigenvalues closest in magnitude to 12
l,_ = eigs(A, 2, sigma = 12)
print(l)
```

This produces:

```
[ 19.52479260+0.j  12.28842653+0.j  11.43948696+0.j  10.89132148+0.j
  10.79397596+0.j]
[ 12.28842653+0.j  11.43948696+0.j]
```

EDIT:
In case you know the eigenvalues in advance, then you could try to calculate the basis of the corresponding [nullspace](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/RankNullspace.html). For example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig, svd, norm
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
from scipy.linalg import orth

def nullspace(A, atol=1e-13, rtol=0):
    A = np.atleast_2d(A)
    u, s, vh = svd(A)
    tol = max(atol, rtol * s[0])
    nnz = (s >= tol).sum()
    ns = vh[nnz:].conj().T
    return ns

np.random.seed(42)

eigen_values = [1,2,3,3,4,5]
N = len(eigen_values)

D = np.matrix(np.diag(eigen_values))

#generate random unitary matrix
U = np.matrix(orth(np.random.random_sample((N, N))))

#construct test matrix - it has the same eigenvalues as D
A = U.T * D * U

#get eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue 3
Omega = nullspace(A - np.eye(N)*3)
_,M = Omega.shape

for i in range(0, M):
    v = Omega[:,i]
    print(i, norm(A*v - 3*v))
```

Comment: What if I want to find all the eigenvectors with eigenvalue 2, but I don't know how many are these?

Comment: Also, if I use eigs with my normal matrix, error message says: ValueError: matrix type must be 'f', 'd', 'F', or 'D'

Comment: you could either use `eigs` with an upper bound estimate for the number of eigenvectors and then filter the result manually, or for example determine the basis of `A - \lambda` directly using svd. As for the error, what is the `type` of your matrix?